# Stuck on LearnStreet Ruby lesson 5.7

Tags: ruby

I'm attempting to learn Ruby through LearnStreet and it looks like I'm stuck on lesson 5.7 ... not sure what I'm missing and the hint that they had provided isn't helping. Any help is appreciated!

7: Method call
Write a method double on object account which returns the double of its input parameter num.

Hint 2
You can call the method double as follows - double(4)

Hint 1
To double a number, you can multiply it by 2. For example num * 2.

my code.

```
def account.double
4*2
end

account.double
=> 8
```

I'm receiving the output but i have to be missing something as it won't let me continue the lesson.

Comment: They probably want you to create a method that you can call with a value to double any input... e.g. double(4) => 8, double(5) => 10, double(512) => 1024

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the exercise expects a method with a parameter.  For example:

```
def double(num)
  2 * num
end

puts double(2) # => 4
puts double(3) # => 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer

def account.double(num)

num * 2

end

account.double(3)